# What's the opposite of Fully Qualified Class Name?

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there a word for a non-fully qualified class name?

Something like Local Class Name, Contextual Class Name, ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use "class name".  The non-fully qualified name is just the word after the `class` keyword.

Comment: Makes sense. I was just wondering if there was an actual name for this!

Comment: For completeness' sake, I just came across the term *short class name*. It's to be noted that this is in the PHP world.